# Delete element with a specific value from an array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use vue.js and I want to delete elements of an array that have specific `id` value.

For example :

I want to delete elements that have `id` of 0. I tried to use the `findindex` and then delete the element but I couldn't implement that, and to use the `splice` method you have to know the index before deleting.

```
"Options": [
{
  "id": 0,
  "option": "A",
  "value": "2"
},
{
  "id": 0,
  "option": "B",
  "value": "1"
},
{
  "id": 0,
  "option": "C",
  "value": "3"
},
{
  "id": 1,
  "option": "A",
  "value": "1"
}
```

Comment: I don't see the relation with vuejs :-/

Comment: well it's just an information , it could be a function that do the job ,  that exist in vue js , who knows :D

Answer (score 0):

One more ([polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Polyfill)):

```js
var array = [{id:1},{id:0},{id:0},{id:2}];
array = array.filter(x => x.id != 0);
console.log(array);
```

`x => x.id != 0` is the same as `function (x) { return x.id != 0; }`.